# column values are not showing up

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why can't I get values `0` in the column when `@processdate date = null` or a Sunday (the transactions are not occurring on Sundays)

This was my original query that only gives me values in the table when `@processdate` is declared as any day of the week that is not Sunday or null
I need It to show me a 0 in the table when `@processdate= null` or any sunday

```
alter procedure USP_CTG_VolumeReport   
    @processdate date = '1/8/2017'
as

declare @date date = coalesce(@processdate, cast( getdate() as date)) 

select    'apa' as  Source,
           cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date)as 'Date',
           count(*) as Total_Count
from apa_2000
where
    cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date) = @date 
group by
    cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date)
```

I should be able to get the proper table with a subquery but for some reason --it is not working
Below is my subquery that is giving me the same result as my previous query

```
select   
    'apa' as Source,
    cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date)as 'Date',
    isnull((select count(*) 
            from apa_2000
            where cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date) = @date) 
           , 0 ) as Total_Count
from apa_2000
where
    cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date) = @date 
group by
    cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date)
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the results you are getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: Source/   Date /  Total_Count                                                                        
 is my result, there are no values below those columns when processdate = null or for example '1/8/2017' ( sunday) .... i would like to see '0' under Total_Count if processdate is null or any day that would be sunday (basically anytime when there is nothing to count i would like to see 0 under Total_count instead a blank line

Comment: Are you always passing in a single date? If so, that will make it easier to resolve.

Comment: yes, however sometimes the date might not be declared in which case it would be null

Comment: And what do you want to do then? Return all rows or no rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that those dates where no processing happens, so the counts would be zero, simply don't exist in the database. You are expecting the query to generate data which isn't there. What you need is a table which includes a list of all the dates you want to report against, and then to match the counts against those dates.

If you are always passing in a single date, the following would work, since the input date is the only date you need:

```
declare @date as date = '20170416'

select
    'apa' as Source,
    @date as 'Date',
    count(apa_2000.AccountID_AssignDT) as Total_Count
from
    (select 1 as x)x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    apa_2000 ON cast(AccountID_AssignDT as date) = @date
```

Comment: Sorry, I made some errors in my first post. Fixed now.

Comment: No worries. Please accept and upvote my answer by way of thanks and to help other users find good answers.